# In Android, when to use a Uri, when to use a path, when to add `file://` before the path when not?

Tags: java, android, file, path, uri

In Android, when to use a Uri, when to use a path, when to add `file://` before the path when not?

I just feel confused that different places need different form of file paths.

Can anyone tell the difference and help me be clear which to use in what situation?

I found that some methods receives a Uri as parameter  while others need path with or without the `file://` prefix.
Is there a clear rule saying where to use what or it's just depending on the programmer's individual preference?

Comment: In what context?
WebViews? Intents? `assets` directory reads?

Comment: This is what I want to be clear about, is this directly connecting to which context I'm in? I know where to use what by experience or after a few trials, just feel difficult to make sure if there is a rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are three different things.

If you are want to add Uri then it can be device sdcard image uri or any specific target uri(Uniform Resource Identifier). see example

If you want to point out or path of assets folder or any folder in your app then you have to put file:/// before it.

These things are path represent in different ways.

Or in any other do you want please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Look When you  are using web services or send request to server you can use `Uri,`
when you making database then always use `PATH = "/data/data/your project Name`
when you want to load a local web file  in your Web view or any other file You can use  `file://`